# Laravel 5.2 form url using named route

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Using `Laravel 5.2`, I have a form in one of my `Blade` templates which I want to open and have it point to a named route, which includes a variable.

Essentially I want the resolved form command to open as follows:;

```
<form method="POST" action="http://my.url.com/dash/varname">
</form>
```

So, using `Blade`, I want to open the form using the named route so if this changes in my `routes.php`, the form will still work.

I am trying to do it as follows:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => "route('dashboard.setup', ['var' => 'varname'])",  'method' => 'post']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

also

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => "dashboard.setup, ['var' => 'varname']",  'method' => 'post']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But this does not work. How can I do this and avoid hard coding the url and variable? Thanks!

Comment: what is the error and problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('dashboard.setup', 'varname'), 'method' => 'post')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. By default, a POST method will be assumed;

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('dashboard.setup', 'varname'))) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```